# Email sending program not working in android

Tags: android, android-intent, email

I have made a simple Emailsending demo in android for the learning purpose,I have reffred it from the Link below:
[enter link description here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/#)

every thing is working fine,But the thing is when i click on "send" button of the application,I shows"No application can perform this task"....in place of showing exixsting email clients of emulator..So can anyone please tell me how can i call email client in my program?

my code is:

**main.java**

```
package com.example.emaildemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button send;
EditText to,sub,msg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Send);
        to=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.to);
        sub=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.subject);
        msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);

        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String s1=to.getText().toString();
                String s2=sub.getText().toString();
                String s3=msg.getText().toString();

                Intent i =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{s1});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, new String[]{s2});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String[] {s3});

                 i.setType("message/rfc822");

                  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an Email client :"));

            }
        });

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run & test on real device only.

If you run this on emulator, you will hit error message : “No application can perform this action“. This code only work on real device.

Comment: No problem, Happy to help. Just mark the answer as solved and close the question...

Comment: bro can u tell me how to close the question?

Comment: What I meant is mark the answer as correct which you did , Thats it... In other words, owner of the post(that's you) has closed his query.. So that no further answers be posted.. You can still get suggestion though if any in future....

Answer (score 0):

By running the program on real device it will  automatically call the existing email clients of your device..!